# Изменение цвета EditText android

Tags: android, android-view

У меня есть EditText, которому я должен задать цвет. Не цвет текста или фона, а цвет самой линии которая является EditText!

Нашел в интернете кучу похожих примеров:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
<solid android:color="#4C000000"/>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

*Но если так делать, то меняется цвет заливки, и рамок вокруг всего EditText.*

**Как можно сделать, чтоб изменить цвет только самой нижней линии ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В стилях измените цвета на нужные Вам значения:

`<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yourColor1</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yourColor2</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/yourColor3</item>
</style>`

Comment: я так делал, и не знаю почему, но  цвет, что при активном поле, что при нормальном одинаковый и не меняется , даже если я задаю другой !!!!

Comment: @Vitaliy http://android-holo-colors.com/ выбираете нужный цвет, ставите `Yes` возле `EditText` и скачиваете ресурсы. Закидывайте к себе и применяйте к `EditText`

Answer (score 3):

Так же, как вариант, можно изменить цвет программно:

```
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

За цвет нижней линии отвечает атрибут **backgroundTint**

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
```

Чтобы убрать нижнюю линию используйте прозрачный цвет

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```